# What parameters will allow Ghostscript to read font names in Chinese correctly from a PDF?

Tags: pdf, fonts, ghostscript, cmd, cjk

I tried

```
gswin32c -sDEVICE=jpeg -sOutputFile=foo.jpg foo.pdf
```

but I get the ff. output from Ghostscript on the page where the Chinese font is used.

```
Substituting CID font resource/Adobe-CNS1 for /·s²Ó©úÅé.
Error: /undefinedresource in --findresource--
Operand stack:
   --dict:4/4(L)--   F3   12.96   --dict:6/6(L)--   --dict:6/6(L)--   ·s²Ó©úÅé --dict:9/12(ro)(G)--   --nostringval--   --dict:8/8(L)--   --dict:8/8(L)--   Adobe-CNS1   CIDFont   Adobe-CNS1
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1   3   %oparray_pop   1   3   %oparray_pop   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   3   1   33   --nostringval--  %for_pos_int_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %array_continue   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push  --nostringval--   %loop_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %array_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %loop_continue   --nostringval--   12   9   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1122/1686(ro)(G)--   --dict:2/20(G)--   --dict:75/200(L)--   --dict:75/200(L)--   --dict:105/127(ro)(G)--   --dict:253/347(ro)(G)--   --dict:21/24(L)--   --dict:4/6(L)--   --dict:26/31(L)--   --dict:20/26(ro)(G)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: No such file or directory
GPL Ghostscript 8.54: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

It's obvious that Ghostscript's encoding is non-Unicode because it got garbage (/·s²Ó©úÅé) when it read the font name which is in Chinese.  [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VL1hM.png) is a screen shot of the Chinese fonts used as listed by Adobe Reader 9.

Comment: it would be helpful if you can post a link to one of these PDFs... I don't have PDFs around which use CID fonts.

Comment: your Ghostscript version is rather old, I might say. 8.51 was released in April 2005, more than 5 years ago! And in these 5 years, *a lot* of progress and improvements was made in the Ghostscript code. You should consider to install 8.71 (currently the latest release) from http://www.ghostscript.com/releases/ .

Comment: Try http://www.csb.gov.hk/english/publication/files/e-hrmguide.pdf.  I think this is where my tester got the PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting problem.

However, it's not necessarily Ghostscript's fault here, that you only see /·s²Ó©úÅé.

From your command, I see you was using Ghostscript on *Windows*, inside a `cmd.exe` shell window. And it is `cmd.exe` which may not be able to display properly what Ghostscript asks it to display. This could have two separate reasons (or both at the same time)

1. the *'codepage'* your cmd.exe window uses cannot handle CID or Unicode characters/glyphs.
2. the font used by your cmd.exe does not contain and therefore cannot handle CID/Unicode glyphs.

You should query your `cmd.exe` window first, which *'codepage'* it uses. Type:

```
chcp
```

and see if it is anything that can ***NOT*** display multi-byte characters and glyphs (like "codepage 850").

If so, try to change your codepage in your current cmd.exe window, using this command:

```
chcp 65001
```

or

```
chcp 65000
```

This should switch you to Unicode (*65001 == UTF-8-Unicode*; *65000 == UTF-7-Unicode*). If you did so, you also have to make sure that ***the font used in your cmd.exe window*** can display all (most) of the glyphs in question: therefore you should go into the settings of the cmd.exe window (click the top left corner icon of window title bar) and change the font to *'Lucida Console'*.

Here are a few more codepage numbers which may help you:

```
932 :  Japanese Shift-JIS
936 :  Simplified Chinese GBK
949 :  Korean
950 :  Traditional Chinese Big5
```

***But note***, you may not be able to switch to these codepages, unless your computer is installed with Japanese/Chinese/Korean language support.

See also here:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake

---

Having said all this above, this may still not solve your problem. Ghostscript may still show the same error, because it is not finding the font it wants to use (***CID font resource/Adobe-CNS1***) in place of ***·s²Ó©úÅé***. But at least you would understand better, which font it wants to replace. Your console would display the same asian glyphs as your Adobe Reader screenshot shows... ;-)

Comment: You seem to be right that it is a code page problem.  I used 65001 and the font name became an undisplayed glyph.  However, I still got the same error.  On the other hand, I've been thinking about the error and it seems that you are right again that it is Adobe-CNS1 that was not located.  It's strange though because AFAIK this comes shipped with GS.

Comment: @Chry Cheng: Is your Ghostscript running on the same system as where you made your Acrobat screenshot (http://imgur.com/4mdmx.png) with the chinese font name?

Comment: If Ghostscript is printing Unicode, then the Windows console aill handle codepage conversions automatically. You'll see question marks in that case, then. When using UTF-8 it's more likely that the results are simply U+FFFD, what unknown code points are converted into. (Indeed, when interpreting above characters as they would appear in code page 850 or 437 as UTF-8 I get only gibberish. This is definitely *not* the problem here.)

Answer (score 0):

Chry Cheng: I'm still trying to find a solution to your problem with Ghostscript, but I didn't have time to do the required research yet...

I don't know if you **must** use Ghostscript for some reason. But if not, here is another option: [**MuPDF**](http://mupdf.com/). Brought to you by artofcode LLC & Artifex Inc. -- the same people that develop Ghostscript.

***And MuPDF didn't have any problem for me to render your example file!***  (Funnily, Ghostscript chokes on page 2; Acrobat Reader also choked, but offered to download and install an additional Asian font, not naming it, but saying it was *"to support traditional Chinese"*. *After installing it, Acrobat Reader however does not show a single chinese glyph on page 2!*)

MuPDF:

- [Open Source](http://mupdf.com/repos/mupdf/);
- multiplatform (Windows, Mac OS X, Unix, ...soon maybe Android, iPhone too?);
- **very** lightweight (see screenshots below);
- **very** fast;
- secure (no JavaScript support);
- **very** surely not bloated with features;
- **does** display all pages of your example PDF
- interface is very simple (keyboard navigation only, no menues or icons):

[image: MuPDF: very simple GUI -- this is all the GUI it has.] [image: MuPDF: keyboard navigation only, no menues or icons.]

---

<sup>(Chry Cheng: I wonder if you also notice that one little thing in my screenshots that was a bit surprising and mysterious for me...)</sup>

Comment: I didn't know MuPDF yet. I downloaded+installed in an instance after reading your answer, and indeed: it is **really** fast (and **very** spartanic in its GUI).

Comment: I require a DLL interface which MuPDF does not seem to have.

Comment: @Chry Cheng: *"MuPDF is a lightweight PDF viewer and toolkit written in portable C. [...] small footprint.  A binary [...] with full CJK support (including an Asian font) is approximately five megabytes. [...] support for all non-interactive PDF 1.7 features [...] provides a simple API for accessing the internal structures of the PDF document. Example code for navigating interactive links and bookmarks, encrypting PDF files, extracting fonts, images, and searchable text, and rendering pages to image files is provided."* (Quote from README)